# Why does removeClass() not act on the inner element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

The class is added but not deleted. When I move the `.closeX` element at the same level in the `.menu` it works, but not when inside.

```js
$('.menu').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('openMenu')
})

$('.closeX').click(function() {
  $('.menu').removeClass('openMenu')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="menu">
  <div class="closeX"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: ``this`` refers to the event trigger, maybe a button. The ``menu`` class doesnt have the class you added, is added to the event trigger.

Comment: The problem when the div is inside is that the remove happens, but then the click propogates to menu, and it re-adds your class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is deleted - but it is being added again. Because `.closeX` is inside of `.menu`, when you click `.closeX` both functions get called, because the click is triggered on both `.closeX` and `.menu`. So the class is removed, and added again.

**Edit:** To fix this, you should either move `.closeX` so it is no longer a child of `.menu`, or if you don't want to change your markup, do as Rory's answer suggests and stop the even propagation with add `e.stopPropagation()` (see Rory's answer for implementation).

Comment: This describes the problem. How do you fix it?

Answer (score 5):

The issue is because `.closeX` is a child of `.menu`. This means that when you click `.closeX` the class is removed. *However* the event bubbles up the DOM to `.menu` which then adds the class back on again.

To fix this call `stopPropagation()` on the inner event handler:

```js
$('.menu').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('openMenu')
})

$('.closeX').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('.menu').removeClass('openMenu')
})
```

```css
.openMenu { background-color: #CCC; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="menu">
  Click me to add class
  <div class="closeX">Click me to remove class</div>
</section>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the event trigger, maybe a `button`. The `menu` class doesn't have the class you added, is added to the event trigger.